# How to lay heat cable (de-icing cable)?

Tags: water, insulation, ice

[image]

The issue I'm having is that ice builds up on the lower roof, creating a dam. The upper attic is double insulated, but is exposed to sun throughout the day. The lower roof (next to the sidewall) only sees sunlight for an hour or two very late in the day. So, the upper roof experiences some melt due to the sun and drops to the lower roof where it freezes creating a large dam against the sidewall. Eventually the ice backs up into the seams causing water entry into the interior.

Everything is insulated well, so I think I need to install de-icing cable along the upper edge, along the sidewall, and a bit at the bottom. See photo below - does this make sense, or is there a better way to lay it? Or are there other alternatives to avoid this issue?

My other consideration, is doing a piece of metal roofing (flashing) along the side wall, where the meltwater  falls on the lower roof.

[image]

Comment: Where on this planet are you? There's probably a better solution to your ice dam woes than brute-forcing it with a heating cable.

Comment: Go to the websites of the manufacturers of the cables. They have extensive routing, layout and length help.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, I disagree. Around here depending on your roof orientation and conditions ice dams are inevitable and very troublesome for some homes.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey -- even in an unvented cathedralized roof configuration with a vented over-roof?  See [this article](http://buildingscience.com/documents/insights/bsi-046-dam-ice-dam) for more details.  (Although the OP's problem isn't a roof *insulation* issue...)

Comment: Also, at the OP: is there meltwater dripping from the upper roof when this is happening?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - I live in Maine. The meltwater is coming off of the upper roof and freezing on the lower roof. The upper roof faces south, and is exposed to sun all day. The lower roof only sees the sun for about 1-2 hours. The upper roof is a standard attic with 12" insulation baffles topped with 12" of blown in insulation. The lower roof is a finished space, with soffit & ridge venting. Water freezes on the lower roof, and creeps back upwards through the joint of where the two roof lines meet.

Comment: @Jason -- how high up are you? (as in, the elevation of your property)

Comment: @Jason -- also, am I correct in assuming the upper roof is insulated but not vented?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - Upper roof has ridge, gable & soffit vents. 284 ft elevation overall, home is in a standard residential neighborhood.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - My other thought is to add a piece of metal roofing/flashing on the lower roof along the sidewall, so that the meltwater  is directed away.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of cable, put a gutter on the upper roof with a down spout directing the runoff past the edge of the lower roof.

Comment: Not a bad idea.

Comment: See this post regarding protecting the lower roof from excess wear due to the runoff.  It's applicable whether you use a gutter and downspout or not.  In fact, you may want to consider some type of drip protection on both sides of the dormer so that water coming off the upper roof does not wear holes in the lower roof.  [link] http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/71585/how-to-prevent-heavy-rainwater-from-jumping-the-gutter/71816#71816