# Upper roof downspout emptying onto lower roof

Tags: roof, gutters, downspout

I have an upper roof downspout emptying onto a lower roof. the downspout exit sits near the side of the lower roof, and water falls off the side before continuing down to fall into the lower roof gutter.

is it possible to install a gutter along the side? is the only solution a downspout extension to the lower gutter? how is the downspout extension secured? We prefer the gutter along the side but can it be attached to the existing lower roof gutter? not sure what type of gutter corner that would require. i don't think we can send the upper roof downspout straight down to the ground due to association rules.

we have two skylights so we can't move the upper roof downspout towards the center of the roof because of how much water is directed out from the upper roof. We want to avoid a leak in the Skylights.

[image]

[image: this roof is only about 10-12 feet long[![][2]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VOF7.jpg)

Comment: Possibly related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/71585/how-to-prevent-heavy-rainwater-from-jumping-the-gutter

Answer (score 2):

We have a similar two story house where we had contractors redo the gutters.  They continued the downspout from the second floor over the roof of the first floor and positioned it directly into the hole in the first floor gutter.

No straps were visible on the run over the first floor and it appears to be secured at the second floor downspout only.

Volume of water has not been given a real test yet.  I direct the output into rain barrels with an overflow facing downhill. You could direct it into 4" perforated pipe with sleeve buried in the ground and running away from the house. This is a [French drain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_drain) which empties into a [dry well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_well).  If you ever wondered how to use up empty plastic pails this is your chance!

Comment: is it attached with some sort of screw to the first floor gutter?

Comment: @Rbell   two 1/3 inch screws are used to attach the first floor run where the second floor downspout is.  I did not see anything where the run goes into the first floor gutters

Comment: I think piping that water from the upper spout to the lower gutter is the ideal solution. If the roof is in a place where leaves or pine needles are prone to collecting, consider whether to elevate the downspout pipe above the singles so that debris won't collect under or around it (collected debris could cause accelerated deterioration of the shingles).

Answer (score 0):

One solution I saw was a 45 bend on the top outlet which “threw” the water into the middle of the roof... worked well and cheap and easy...

Comment: i thought that water flowing diagonally across shingles risks water getting underneath them since they're designed to have water flow downward