# Connecting downspout to first floor gutter

Tags: roof, gutters, downspout

I am looking to connect my second floor downspout to the first floor gutter.  In any sort of wind, the water misses the gutter completely and makes a big mess.  I found the [thread here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/71591/107144) very helpful for what I want to do but being new I cannot comment on it.  What I cannot determine is if there is anything special I need to do to attach the downspout to the roof?  Will 2 gutter screws at the top A style elbow be enough?  I'm trying to avoid putting holes in the roof!

[image]

**Update:**

I ended up using 2 A style 45 degree elbows, since the standard 70 degree elbows were too much.  I then connected the downspout and gutter with the appropriate tiny screws.  It's pretty sturdy and tonight's expected wind storm+rain should be a good test.

I wish I could get the colors to match better -- I bought Linen, but I think I needed Almond.  Oh well...

[image]

Comment: I'd give serious consideration to just re-routing that downspout down the side of the house all the way to the ground - looks like it drains a fairly large roof area.

Comment: I agree with Ecnerwal.  That much  water will probably overflow the gutter and you'd still have a big mess

Comment: How has it been? Any issues with overflowing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not put holes into roof.

Two screws into the outflow.  If you are in a hurricane area or someplace with crazy winds you could put another 90 into the gutter which will keep the section on the roof from moving around too much.  If you still feel that isn't adequate you could secure the lower gutter 90 to the lower gutter.

Comment: I'd definitely attach to the elbow and to the gutter below. Counting shingle rows to estimate distance, it looks like the connection will be almost 6 feet long. It wouldn't take much force, whether from wind or from somebody cleaning debris from the lower gutter, to knock that downspout and damage the stuff up on the wall.