# How to handle rainwater on this awkward roof edge?

Tags: water, roof, roofing, gutters

I’m trying to evaluate/troubleshoot this gutter system to better manage rainwater runoff. I wonder if this spot here may cause issues, and if so, how to handle it.

[image]

Water runs off the narrow edge directly onto the roof below. The lower roof does have a gutter, but because the edge above is so narrow and steep the runoff is fast and hits a concentrated area on the (much flatter) deck below. It sounds like someone is pouring a bucket on this one spot every time it rains.

I’m concerned this will wear out the lower roof too quickly (if it hasn’t already).

I’ve been readying about splash blocks and drip guards and considered adding onto the gutter but I don’t know if any of those options apply here.

Comment: This thread might inspire you: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/71585/how-to-prevent-heavy-rainwater-from-jumping-the-gutter

Answer (score 2):

That roof edge needs a short gutter with a downspout that drains into the lower gutter.

The crashing water is a problem for both roof longevity and water intrusion. Where two construction materials meet is usually a weak spot for water; in this case it's the lower roofing and the siding.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional guttering approach would be a gutter with downspout (probably running down the outside corner, then across the lower roof) directed into the gutter below, in its direction of flow.

The sloppier approach would just dump that downspout onto the roof below near the wall, and hope it didn't overflow the gutter on the roof it's dumping onto. Given how small the roof area is that would be served, that might actually work.